# How to re-send a failed SMS with Zenvia in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms

I'm using Rails with Zenvia API to send Text Messages to my users.
But if a message fails to send, how could I send the same message without creating a new message ID? Is there a method to it?
Today when I try to send again the same message, it returns "Message with same ID already sent".

Comment: Please provide us with relevant code and show us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Zenvia API does not have a way to resend messages with same ID. At least not within 24 hours.

The solution I found was to create a token that would serve as a "fake" ID and passed it to the API. If the message for any reason fails to send, I create a new token and send it again.